# mysql error for a create table statement from shell client

Tags: mysql, shell

Im trying to run the following from the mysql shell client:

```
MySQL  localhost:33060+ ssl  plaything  SQL > CREATE TABLE areas (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, area_name VARCHAR);
```

and keep getting the following error:
ERROR: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

where could I be going wrong?

Comment: try this: CREATE TABLE areas (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    area_name varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

Comment: and please provide more info about mysql version

Comment: IT WORKED! thank you so much, there must have been something wrong with my syntax. And I think it's version 8.0

Comment: 'there must have been something wrong with my syntax' - yup you need to specify length of varchar datatypes - serial is fine.

Comment: Yes there was varchar has ti have a number of bytes like CREATE TABLE areas (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, area_name VARCHAR(9));

Comment: those statements were copied over from my work with postgres, i didnt realise there were differences in syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by yoss:

try this: CREATE TABLE areas ( id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, area_name varchar(255), PRIMARY KEY (id) );

varchar did not have number of characters specified in the original statement

Comment: This isn't useful because you don't explain what was wrong with original query.